# Let's let this tag [die]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [die](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/die) (currently 216 questions) needs to die.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, questions relate to at least three different concepts that are not related at all.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it's too ambiguous.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, questions in the tag currently relate to at least three different concepts:

- Coding or modeling probability in die/dice rolls, often for game purposes.
- Terminating applications, processes, or threads (often with a method call named "die").
- Statistical modeling of death rates in living creatures.

Let's let this tag die. Questions related to rolling, modeling, or sampling die or dice rolls should be retagged [dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dice), and questions about terminating processes or threads should be retagged [terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminate).

Comment: It has a description that clearly states what it is for and I don't think that anyone would get it confused with dice related uses or stats modeling of living things on a programing site.

Comment: @JoeW [It happens more often than you'd think](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdie%5D+dice&mixed=0)

Comment: @JoeW [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53661713/6471538) a question where it is being used to mean modeling life and death.

Comment: @JoeW but does that add anything meaningful to the question, that most likely isn't already contained in the body of said question?

Comment: @Luuklag also, tags are supposed to be used so that experts can find questions they can answer. It's reasonable for someone to know a lot about dice and how to model them for role playing games and whatnot, but less reasonable for someone to be an expert in terminating threads. That last one is arguably a meta tag too, as the nuances of terminating a thread in Java may be rather different than terminating one in Win32.

Comment: @JoeW that "description... clearly states" at least three different things. Hard to call that unambiguous. "In Perl, die raises an exception or aborts the program. In PHP, die exits the program. In jQuery, the die method removes an event handler."